# Custom frontend controller returns 404

Tags: controllers, magento1.9.3

I disabled Magento cache before I began to work on this.

I can see my module is visible in "System/Configuration/Advance/Disable Modules Output" listing.

But if I call this module as http://localhost/mag/index.php/mymodule/index I get `404 Not Found` error.

Can you please point out where I'm doing wrong here? I need to understand why.

Thanks in advance

Here are my codes

**app/code/local/Mycompany/mymodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>            
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompnay_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'hello World!';
    }   
}
```

Comment: Is your controller on **app/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php** location? It should be **app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php**

Comment: Thanks Jaimin, Yes my controller is its under app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers/IndexControlle‌​r.php previously it was a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo mistake in **app/code/local/Mycompany/mymodule/etc/config.xml**
You have used `Mycompnay_Mymodule` inplace of `Mycompany_Mymodule` at line

```
<module>Mycompnay_Mymodule</module>
```

There is one more change you need to do to make it work.
Open your **app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Mymodule.xml**
change

```
<codepool>local</codepool>
```

To

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

With a capital `P`

It should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Jaimin, I did change it and was expecting that it was the reason.. and double checked all other codes line by line for any typo. But still the same.

Comment: @Roshanruzaik Please check updated answer.

Comment: Spot on Jaimin! indeed this was the mistake I did. Its now working.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your router name `<mymoduleroutename>` It's should be `<mymodule>`

> Update this below code in your file path:-

**app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>            
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompnay_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> I Hope It's helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Umesh, I changed it to <mymodule> but still the same.

Comment: Please clear cache once again and check @Roshanruzaik

Comment: Thanks for the tip Umesh. But actual reason was <codepool> . I 'v already selected the correct solution.

Comment: cool@Roshanruzaik